# JQuery extension - Youtube playlist - selecting checkbox not recognized as manual click

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm trying to get some feel for JQuery etc.
Currently, my aim is to write a simple browser extension that selects all "deleted videos" in a playlist and removes them.

The selection is going fine, also works with the alternative commented lines:

```
var allVideos = $(".playlist-video-item.hidden");
alert("Nbr of deleted videos to remove: " + allVideos.length);
jQuery.each(allVideos, function(){
    //$(this).find(":checkbox").attr("checked", true)[0].onclick();
    //$(this).find(":checkbox").click();
    $(this).find(":checkbox").trigger('click');
});
$("#playlist-edit-actions").click(); // button not editable??
```

However, even though some videos are "checked", the Actions button on top remains disabled. Only when I add another click manually, it becomes editable.

The solution is probably simple? I've looked around a bit for simulating native clicks but didn't see an immediate answer.

Regards.